# $\arctan$ of constant multiplied $\tan \varphi$

Tags: trigonometry

Helllo, I'm new here. I will try this great place to get my answer. I have a next problem:

$$\vartheta = \arctan(K \tan \varphi)$$

$K > 0$

Where $K$ is a constant. If $K = 1$ then $\vartheta = \varphi$, but I can't find more simple answer for $\vartheta$ if $K \neq 1$. Maybe someone will be able to help me out, if it is even possbile.

Comment: So what is your question? What do you need to derive? Do you have to find $\theta$ ?

Comment: A solution to $\vartheta = \arctan(K \tan \varphi)$ is an intersection of the graphs of $\tan x$ and $K\tan x$ in the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.  But there is only one such intersection  when $K \neq 1$: the intersection at $x = 0$.  See [this plot](http://i.imgur.com/6ZYJQ.png).

Comment: @Antonio: The question asks for $\vartheta=\arctan(K\tan(\varphi))$ not $\varphi=\arctan(K\tan(\varphi))$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas it looks like you're finding values of x for which $\tan(x)$ and $K\tan(x)$ are equal, but the OP is seeking the relationship between $x$ and $y$ where $\tan(x)=K\tan(y)$. For example, $\theta = \pi/3$,$\phi = \pi/6$, $K=3$ works.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I would like to get simpler form for $\vartheta$ if $K \neq 1$. I was wondering if there exists any derivation of that form.

Comment: There are formulas for $\tan(K\arctan(x))$ for certain values of $K$, but I don't know of any for $\arctan(K\tan(\varphi))$.

Comment: @robjohn: Whoops, you're right.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Ctheta+%3D+arctan%28K+tan%28%5Cphi%29%29

Comment: Grega, what do you mean by "simpler"?  We could, for example, use the [exponential form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Exponential_definitions) of $\tan$ to derive the [logarithmic form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms) of $\arctan$, then combine these in $\vartheta = \arctan(K \tan \varphi)$ and simplify to get $$\vartheta = \frac{i}{2} \text{Log}\left(\frac{1-e^{2 i \varphi} (K-1)+K}{1+e^{2 i \varphi} (K+1)-K}\right).$$

Comment: If $K$ is a positive integer, then $\tan(Kx)$ can be expressed as a not horrible rational function of $\tan x$. You then end up solving a polynomial equation of degree $K$. I doubt there is a general expression for the roots. For non-integer $K$, the problem is likely to be hopeless.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for answers. I knew if there was anything simple possible I would find it already.

Comment: If an approximation is enough,$$\vartheta=K\,\varphi+\frac{1}{3} \left(K-K^3\right)\varphi^3 + O(\varphi^5)$$

Comment: If the tan and arctan were reversed, it would be a lot easier.  I know of no way offhand to represent $\arctan kx$ in terms of $\arctan x$

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I knew I have a tough one. I just left it the way it is, because in that way it bothers my derivations at a minimum :).

Comment: Since wolframalpha is providing exact solutions, there must be a better method...